# Enable WMQ statistics

Tags: ibm-mq

I tried doing the following: 
alt ql(somequeue) statq(on)
alt qmgr statq(on)
alt qmgr statint(30)
RESET QMGR TYPE(STATISTICS)

But nothing appears in the SYSTEM.ADMIN.STATISTICS.QUEUE. I even tried to set the Inhibit GET on the queue to make sure noone is stealing the messages.

Why are the statistics not showing?

Answer (score 4):

If your description lists all that you did, and there are no error messages in your queue manager error log, then best guess is that there was nothing to report!

If I do exactly that, I get no messages on the SYSTEM.ADMIN.STATISTICS.QUEUE either.

However, if before issuing the RESET command, I put a couple of messages to the queue in question, then I get some statistics on the SYSTEM.ADMIN.STATISTICS.QUEUE.